# Confused by MongoDb documentation Collection.remove

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections

I'm just learning how use mongoDb and I get confused by the documentation about the `Collection.remove()` method.

In first place, I tried to follow this doc:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/

But I got the message `Error: Cannot use a writeConcern without a provided callback`, so I searchd why and I found this documentation then: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html

In the first one there are two args, in the second there are three.

Then I did a `console.log((mongodb.Collection(db, 'user').remove).toString());`

And I got `function remove(selector, options, callback)...`

So now I just don't understand what's going on here, Is there different kind of Collection class? I whish to understand which documentation I should follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you just have to provide a callback-function:

```
Collection.remove(function(err, removedCount) {
    //your next actions
});
```

From [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#remove):

> [callback] (function) – must be provided if you performing a remove with a writeconcern

Comment: Hum yes, I know that now, the point is why it's not described in the mongodb docs? Plus I also need to provide a query, it's not optional. (Except if I want delete everything...)

Comment: @Vadorequest there are two kinds of documentations: for the node.js connector to MongoDB, and to MondoDB itself. You should follow the [first one](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html)

Comment: Is it written somewhere in the docs.mongodb website and I missed it? It's really confusing! Well, i'll follow the node.js connector doc now, but I still don't exactly understand why it's not written somewhere that we should read another documentation if we are using node.js..

Comment: @Vadorequest it was confusing for me too :) By the way, there is another one MongoDB connector for node.js - [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) - and it has its own documentation too

Comment: Ahah, I use also mongoose. Dat joke. But here I'm with `mongo-migrate` and I don't think it uses it, so I'll have to deal with doc from two connectors, wonderful ^^